# Jazz quartets without chord instrument

Tags: theory, jazz, saxophone, arranging, trumpet

I want to write my degree thesis in music theory on arranging for jazz quartets without chord instruments (i.e. Vibraphone, piano, guitar...). For instance, there are the recordings of Gerry Mulligan and Chet Baker or the Yay Yennings Quartet by the Snarky Puppy  trumpet player Jay Jennings. 
My teacher told me to look for piece to compare to the Baker/mulligan recordings. For example an idea would be to look for a large ensemble arrangement of the piece or to compare a different quartet playing the same piece. 
My Question is: What other quartets without chord instruments do you know to compare to and if not, what larger ensembles do you know that recorded the same pieces and have transcriptions online? I ask specifically for the large ensemble transcription, since I'm most certain I can handle the quartet setting by trancsribing.

Comment: It might not be exactly what you want, but maybe Milhaud's _La Creation du Monde_ would be helpful. The score is at imslp.org

Answer (score 2):

Welp... the string quartet is by definition four mainly non-chordal instruments, and there's the Turtle Island String Quartet. They recorded a lot of standards (I think they have a whole album of Coltrane), and since they were the "cool kids" to string students in the 90s-2000s, many of their transcriptions are published.

However, that might have too much of the work "done" for you, if your job is primarily just arranging. If you want to give yourself more license to add creatively, you could look into translating their arrangements to more idiomatic for other instruments, or maybe expand their solo cello hit "Julie-O" for a quartet.

In terms of arranging from a larger ensemble to smaller, I'm sure this has been done before but you could look into adapting some of the jazz-influenced symphonic works like "Rhapsody in Blue" for smaller ensemble, or even "jazz up" works from other genres, as Duke Ellington did with *The Nutcracker*. (Though... I dunno. Many people try that stunt, and many people are not Duke Ellington.)

Comment: Thank you for your ideas with the Turtle Island String Quartet. I have never hear of them but will definitely give them a listen. I also like the idea to rearrange their music into other instruments. I originally planned on analyzing different quartets (bass, drums, trp, sax) to find out  about general tendencies. Do you know other quartets in that formation? Furthermore, the arranging bock by Bill Dobbins is one of the books I used in my arranging class. I thought of analyzing the tunes under his point of view.